# Import nodejs module

Tags: meteor

I'm using meteor 1.4.2.3 and I would like to import the NodeJs net module? I tried to import it, on the server side, with `import net from 'net';`, but that didn't work. Net is undefined.

```
import net from 'net';

export class Print {
  private printAsync(callback){
    let client = new net.Socket();

  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From a fresh `meteor create` project, the following works for me.

In `/server/main.js`:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  // code to run on server at startup
});

import net from 'net';

export class Print {
  printAsync(callback){
    let client = new net.Socket();
    console.log(client);
  }
}

console.log(net);
const print = new Print();
print.printAsync();
```

Output in the console:

```
I20161129-07:59:18.007(-8)? { createServer: [Function],
I20161129-07:59:18.008(-8)?   createConnection: [Function],
I20161129-07:59:18.008(-8)?   connect: [Function],
I20161129-07:59:18.008(-8)?   _normalizeConnectArgs: [Function: normalizeConnectArgs],
I20161129-07:59:18.008(-8)?   Socket: { [Function: Socket] super_: { [Function: Duplex] super_: [Object] } },
I20161129-07:59:18.008(-8)?   Stream: { [Function: Socket] super_: { [Function: Duplex] super_: [Object] } },
I20161129-07:59:18.009(-8)?   Server: 
I20161129-07:59:18.009(-8)?    { [Function: Server]
[...]
I20161129-07:59:18.012(-8)? Socket {
I20161129-07:59:18.013(-8)?   _connecting: false,
I20161129-07:59:18.013(-8)?   _hadError: false,
I20161129-07:59:18.013(-8)?   _handle: null,
I20161129-07:59:18.013(-8)?   _parent: null,
I20161129-07:59:18.013(-8)?   _host: null,
I20161129-07:59:18.013(-8)?   _readableState: 
I20161129-07:59:18.020(-8)?    ReadableState {
I20161129-07:59:18.020(-8)?      objectMode: false,
I20161129-07:59:18.020(-8)?      highWaterMark: 16384,
[...]
```

I'm not able to reproduce your undefined `net`.

Comment: I'm importing it on the server side, but the import doesn't work.

Comment: Huh, it works for me. Do you have a sample repo or can you provide more context?

Comment: I updated the question. The variable net is undefined. How did you import the net module? Did you install the npm package?

Comment: Removing the "private" keyword works for me. No, I didn't need to install an npm package.

Comment: Could you please post your code. It does not work in my case. Net is always undefined.

Comment: Updated my answer with the code and console output. Try it out, hope that helps...